# Notebook won't save

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

Running Mathematica 13.0 (home edition) on macOS Monterey Version 12.5

I worked on an existing notebook this morning and saved the notebook at 11:05 AM without incident.

After further work, some 20 minutes later I attempted to save the notebook again and the following popped up:

[image]

Between saving the document at 11:05 AM and attempting to save it again, I made no changes to permissions of directories or anything else.

I only edited some simple code (which worked and continues to work).

Of note:

- I have no problems saving other kinds of files.
- I can save the notebook to a different directory (file folder).

Any thoughts on what could cause this and how to fix this appreciated?

---

**Updates**:

This issue has now spread to other directories and other notebooks.

I do not have this issue when saving other types of files; it seems, at least for now, a Mathematica issue.

Comment: On my Mac, I have a program called F-Secure running in the background. This program occasionally triggers permission warnings for third-party (= non- native Apple) software. But never with MMA notebooks, as far as I recall.

Comment: I have nothing like F-Secure running.  Mysterious problem.