# You're running in a mode which does not allow saving files

Tags: warning-messages, save

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? 
(13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022))

[image]

Comment: Are you using a trial version? Because that's part of its limitations. Otherwise, this looks like a question for [their Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Is this under the Wolfram Player?

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion no, I'm using the student version.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino no, I'm thinking if it has anything to do with the files on cloud.

Comment: I have a similar issue, see: [Notebook won't save](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273785/notebook-wont-save).  In my case I can save a file to a new filename, but I can't save additional work on the file to the same filename.  I've had no response on this forum, the community forum, or Wolfram support.  Weird problem.

Comment: @Jagra I also have that issue as well.

Comment: Have you made any major changes to you computer hardware?  You may need to reactivate.